# Is there a back-pressure mechanism from qdisc to TCP?

Tags: tcp, tc

Is there a mechanism to stop TCP sending packets towards Qdisc if the queue length exceeds the limit?
I know TSQ helps here for a small number of connections but what if I have 1000 connections or more?

I can't find in the code any function that will stop TCP. But I do find in `sch_fq.c` for example:

```
if (unlikely(sch->q.qlen >= sch->limit))
        return qdisc_drop(skb, sch, to_free);
```

Thanks

EZ

Answer (score 0):

It would not make much sense if there was such as mechanism because TCP is only one kind of traffic on the limited interface. And the logic which traffic is tropped is in the traffic shaping layer.

Furthermore it should not be necessary, especially for TCP, as TCP has its own limiting function.